# Facebook bot - retrieve image sent by user

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I would like to know if this is possible for the Bot to retrieve an image directly send by the user in the messenger chat. (e.g. Get the image of a fire extinguisher on server side and save it)

I know there is this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117083/how-to-receive-image-in-facebook-messenger-bot) but because I'm in a case study, I need to know the "theorical" possibility so the response in it, doesn't match with my question.
The messenger bot documentation give only a example with texte and doesn't mention image.

Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes according to the documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference